# Visual Studio - How to get show all files in solution explorer to skip a folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, solution-explorer

When I press the Show All Files button in the Visual Studio 2008 Solution Explorer it takes several minutes for Visual Studio to respond. This is because there is an images folder under the solution that contains thousands of files. Is there any way to get Show All Files to not display this folder?

Answer (score 2):

Put the images folder somewhere else, outside the solution folder.  If they're part of a website, create a virtual directory for them.

IMO there shouldn't be any files in the solution folder that are not part of the solution anyways.